# Не видится this.переменная при вызове обработчика

Tags: jquery, javascript

Привет.

Такая проблема.

`this.width`, инициализированный вызовом конструктора, при непосредственном вызове функции `showNextPicture` равен 130 - как надо, а если вызвать эту функцию через `onclick` - то `undefuned`. Почему?

код:

```
function Carousel(width, count){
        this.width = width;
        this.count = count;
    }

Carousel.prototype.init = function(){
// код
}

Carousel.prototype.showNextPicture = function(){
console.log(this.width); // 130 - если вызвать прямо, undefined - если по щелчку мыши
}

var carousel = new Carousel(130, 5);   
carousel.init(); 
//carousel.showNextPicture();

// Обработчики событий
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener("click", carousel.showNextPicture, false);
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener("click", carousel.showPreviousPicture, false);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ну наверно так:

```
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener("click", function() {
    carousel.showNextPicture();
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
document.getElementById('prev').addEventListener(
    "click",
    carousel.showPreviousPicture.bind( carousel), // обновил эту строку
    false
);
```

Обновил ответ, спасибо за комментарий [[@lampa](/users/5030/lampa)](/users/5030/lampa)

Comment: Прикол то в том, что передается контекст элемента `prev`, а ТС хочет получить контекст созданного объекта `carousel`. 

Причем у вас в примере передается `this`, а `this` будет указывать на `window`

Такие вот дела: http://jsfiddle.net/kP9bj/

Comment: Я почему-то подумал, что приведенный код - часть того, что обернуто в объект пользователя. Обновил ответ.

Comment: @sergiks ну да, если был бы объект, то да) 

А если этот скрипт в объекте, то можно и вот так:

 Carousel.prototype.setAction = function(elem, type) {
  this.handleEvent = this.showNextPicture;
  document.getElementById(elem).addEventListener(type || "click", this, false);
 }

Answer (score -1):

в jquery пробуйте так:

```
console.log($(this).width());
```

используйте силу jquery и тут. можно заменит это:

```
document.getElementById('next').addEventListener("click", carousel.showNextPicture, false);
```

на это

```
$('#next').live('click',carousel.showNextPicture);
```

Comment: Все два примера неправильные. Первый выведет не свойство объекта, а ширину элемента. Второй, во-первых, выдаст ошибку синтаксиса, а во-вторых, проинициализирует метод `showNextPicture()` и добавит на событие `click` `undefined`, т.к. метод ничего не возвращает. Ну и сам метод `jquery` `live()` уже является [`deprecated`][1] и удален в 1.9 версии.


  [1]: http://api.jquery.com/live/